# Divergent set in terms of unions and intersections

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $(f_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $f $ be real valued functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$. For $ε > 0$ and $\forall m ∈ \mathbb{N}$ define $E_m (ε) = \{x ∈ \mathbb{R}\, |\, |f_m (x) − f(x)| ≥ ε\}$. Let $S = \{x ∈ \mathbb{R} \,|\, {f_n (x)},n\in \mathbb{N}$, does not converge to $f(x)\}.$ Express $S$ in terms of the sets $E_m (ε)$, $m∈\mathbb{N}$, $ε>0$ (using the set theoretic operations of unions and intersections).

I think the answer is $\bigcup_{ε>0}\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{m=n}^{\infty}E_m(ε)$, but am unable to derive it. Any help. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: @user71352 thanks, why did you not write an answer directly instead of posting 3 comments? And the union and intersection must be interchanged in your comment.

Comment: It appears I have made an error. I will remove my comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

Take the def'n of convergence and observe from it that $(f_n(x))_n$ does NOT converge to $f(x)$ iff for some    $e>0$ the set $\{m:|f_m(x)-f(x)|>e\}$ is infinite.

For ease of notation let $F_n(e)=\cup_{m\geq n}E_m(e).$

(1).  If $(f_n(x))_n$ does not converge to $f(x)$.  For some  $e >0$ we have: For every $n$ there exists $m\geq n$ such that $x\in E_m(e).$ Hence  for some $e>0$ we have:  $x\in F_n(e)$ for all $n.$

So $x\in \cap_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n(e)$ for some $e>0$. Therefore $$x\in \cup_{e >0}\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} F_n(e).$$

(2). On the other hand if $x\in \cup_{e>0}\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n(e)$.  For some $e>0$ we have:  $x\in F_n(e)=\cup_{m\geq n}E_m(e)$ for every  $n.$

So for some $e >0$  we have: For every  $n$ there exists $m\geq n$ such that $x\in E_m(e).$ From this, and the def'n of $E_m(e)$, we have, for some  $e >0$ :   For every $n$ there exists  $m\geq n$ with $|f_m(x)-f(x)|>e.$

So for some $e >0 $  the set  $\{m:|f_m(x)-f(x)|>e \}$ is infinite. Therefore  $ (f_n(x))_n$ does not converge to $x.$

Comment: Thank you for correcting me. I shall delete my comments from the comment section.