# Express E in terms of the $E_n$ using the set theoretic operations of union and intersection.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let X be a non-empty set and let $\{En\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of subsets of $X$. Let $E ⊂ X$ be the set of all points in $X$ which lie in infinitely many of the $E_n.$ Express E in terms of the $E_n$ using the set theoretic operations of
union and intersection.

Im completely struck

pliz help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E=\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} \cup_{m=n}^{\infty} E_m$. [A point belongs to infinitely many of the sets $E_n$ iff for each $n$ there is at least one $m>n$ such that the point belongs to $E_m$].

Comment: sir    why E= $\bigcup_{ε>0}\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{m=n}^{\infty}E_m(ε)$  not written ???  why u did n't put$\bigcup_{ε>0}$  ??  what is the  reason

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. What do you mean by $E_m(\epsilon)$?

Comment: @ kavi  sir 
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2081395/divergent-set-in-terms-of-unions-and-intersections.......im   confusing  here  answer is  different ...pliz  clarified  differnce  between  ur answer

Comment: @Messififa Your question here is different from the one in that post. There are no functions here. If you first understand the answer for this question you can go back and study the answer to the question in that post.

Comment: @  Kavi sir thanks  u ..

Answer (score 1):

$E=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty }({\bigcup_{m=n}^{\infty }E_{m})} $.